# Tmux loop through array in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, tmux

I have a complex bash script, one of hist part need to run tmux session and monitor remote servers. Servers list included in array ${servers[@]}. So need to start ssh session for each host in array and execute screen -r.

Each new host ssh session should be started in new pane divided horizontally. And one pane should be vertical and has controls like: kill all tmux sessions and exit to primary terminal window without killing tmux session.
Terminal  window assuming to see:

```
| host0 | host1 | host2| host3...
|       |       |      |
|       |       |      |
|       |       |      | 
---------------------------------
[Q]uit all tmux sessions [Enter] to back in terminal
--------------------------------
```

A function in bash script which suppose to do these actions below, but it lacks controls and not tested for work.

```
#!/bin/bash
servers[0]="host0"
servers[1]="host1"
servers[1]="host2"
SESSIONNAME="monitoring"

tmux has-session -t $SESSIONNAME $&gt; /dev/null
if [ $? != 0 ]; then  
  tmux new-session -s $SESSIONNAME -n monitor -d
  for host in "${servers[@]}"; do
    tmux split-window -t $SESSIONNAME:0 -h      
    tmux send-keys "ssh root@$host" C-m
    tmux send-keys 'screen -r' 'C-m'
  done
fi
tmux select-window -t $SESSIONNAME:0
tmux attach -t $SESSIONNAME
```

Comment: Please test it. If it's broken and you can't fix it, please explain exactly what it did, and what you expected it to do. Include any error messages that appear.

Comment: Tested on 3 remote hosts and produce such output http://simplest-image-hosting.net/png-0-tmuxt   So created 4 panes and left one is empty and too wide.